# Opening and Closing a Frame

Tags: python

I am able to get a frame to open from a button. I can close the frame and reopen it from the same button but it throws an error everytime I push the button.

What is throwing the error in my code is `root.Show()` , it gives me a `AttributeError Show` error

My question is,  although it is working beautifully, could it develop a serious problem for my application?

EDIT: This is the code in my python file

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Help")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

help_message = 'This is the help menu. Please scroll through the menu to find the answer to your question'

txt = Text(root, wrap=WORD) # wrap=CHAR, wrap=NONE
txt.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
txt.insert(END, help_message)

txt.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, state=DISABLED)
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)

root.Show()
```

It is taking the error from the last line of this program. And this is the error in the command prompt:
[image: Error description]

Comment: Can you please show both your code and the full text of the `AttributeError`?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant portions of your application, can you also tell us what framework you are using... probably Tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `root.Show()`, added a button that has to be clicked in order for the window to stay hidden but running. I then added in the main file `HelpBox.root.deiconify()` which makes the screen pop up. If the user does click the "X" button, then the help menu cannot be reopened until they restart the application.

Thanks for everyone's help and ideas

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to use `root.mainloop()`, because I don't see anywhere the method Show or show (Python is case sensitive, and methods/functions are usually lower_case_with_underscores).

The `mainloop` function essentially waits for the program to end, but if you have things like buttons, you can have Tkinter call a certain function to respond (event driven).

Comment: Doesn't work. After I close the popped up window, I push the button and nothing happens. Is there a way to see if a user pushes the "x" button?